# How can I perform a VBA script on click?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using a checkbox Legacy Form Field in my Word document. And I want to perform a VBA script each time I change the status of the checkbox. I thought I would have to perform this VBA script `on event` (no. 1 in the picture). But if I chose either no. 1 or no. 2, it only performs the VBA script if I'm changing to the next field.

[image: on event, on exit, calculate result]

My questions:

Now, how can I perform a VBA script on each click? And what is the difference between no. 2 and no. 3 in the picture above?

Answer (score 0):

Word has no on event triggers for checkboxes if i remember correctly.

A possible workaround would be some kind of validation button which checks the value of the checkbox and then executes the appropriate commands.

Comment: Problem is: there is -afaik- no button in Legacy Form Fields